# Defferent results crontab or manual

Tags: linux, cron

I made a small script which controlls the connection from a server in a NDB Cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/var/log/cluster-check.log"

ndb_mgm -e "show"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "cluster-ok" > $file
else
    echo "cluster-broken" > $file
fi
```

And this is how I implement it to the crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /script/cluster-check.sh
```

I use two kind of servers. One system is the MGM and the other the NDB and API Server. On the MGM server the script works great and I can check the file it generates. The other side is the Data Node. When I start the script by hand it checks correctly and I get the right answer back. When the crontab do the work the answer is always a "cluster-broken".

MGM Server:

```
Oct  4 13:30:01 mysql-master1 /USR/SBIN/CRON[945]: (root) CMD (/script/cluster-check.sh)
```

NDB & API Server:

```
Oct  4 13:33:01 mysql-node1 /USR/SBIN/CRON[29782]: (root) CMD (/script/cluster-check.sh)
```

Any tipps where the problem could come from?

Comment: This would be more appropriate in [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) because it has nothing to do with programming... But it is likely because `ndb_mgm` could not be found with the default crontab path. Did you try to use the full path name instead: `/path/to/ndb_mgm`?

Comment: That works absolutly fine. Thank you Serge.